# django filter values_list

Tags: django, filter

I have a checkbox where I am selecting variables for django filter values.
I am getting the values correctly so if I replace `*values` with `pfast_type[0]` or `pfast_type[1]` it works fine.

But What I want to do is that if I select 3 variables checkbox I want this entered like `pfast_type[0]`, `pfast_type[1]` and `pfast_type[2]`, if I select one 1 variable it should be only `pfast_type[0]` for the values.

Where am I going wrong?

Maybe I am searching poorly but I searched and couldn't find any reference information within the StackOverflow.

```
pfast_type = request.GET.getlist("pfast_type")
elif pfast_type and items:
    for pfast_type in range(len(pfast_type)):
        values= values.append(pfast_type[i])
        object_list = FP.objects.filter(pk__in=items).values('RFP_Item',*values)
```

Comment: try to add meaning to your variable names. your code is hard to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need *values and the loop, simply try this:

```
object_list = RFP.objects.filter(pk__in=items).values('FP_Item',*pfast_type)
```